# Find all distinct regex results, not all in one line

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to find all different parameters passed to the `__()` function in my project. So far the best `grep` call I've constructed is this one:

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep "__('.*')" -sioh
```

It successfully finds all calls to the `__()` function, but it has the following problems:

1. It prints the entire `__()` function call instead of only the parameter
2. It prints both function calls in the same line when there are multiple  calls to the function in the same line in the original file

What I want is a list of all distinct parameters passed to the function, so I would like each parameter to be in its own line (no `__(` at the beginning and no `)` at the end).

For an example line that looks like this:

`/* Some code  */ __('foo'); /* Some more code */ __('bar'); /* Even more code */`

My command returns the following result:

`__('foo'); /* Some more code */ __('bar')`

What I would like to get is this (in their distinct lines without quotes):

```
foo
bar
```

**Edited:**

As it turns out, the first argument is not always a single quoted string. Sometimes it's a variable (starting with a `$` sign as it's PHP in question, and optionally having array indexes, e.g. `$a['b']`).

And there are two more optional boolean arguments. But it's only the first argument I actually care about getting in the result, the other two are not important.

Comment: Please clarify whether _all_ the `__()` calls in your input files have exactly 1, single-quoted argument.

Comment: Actually, as it turns out, no they don't. And that's something I only found out after I ran some of these solutions. They sometimes get a variable in (starting with a `$` as PHP is in question, and optionally having array indexes, e.g. `$a['b']`), and there are two more optional boolean arguments.

Comment: I should probably add that it's only the first argument I actually care about getting in the result. The other two are not important.

Comment: I see; see my update. You should probably add your clarifications to the question, noting them as later addition so as not to invalidate older answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>This answer assumes the following, in line with the OP's later clarification:

- `__()` calls in the input data have 1-3 arguments, *not* necessarily single-quoted.

- Only the 1st argument should be extracted.

- The 1st argument itself contains neither `,` nor `)`.</sup>

Try the following, which should work on most platforms:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -sioh "__([^,)]*" {} + | cut -c 4-
```

- `-exec` with `+` ensures that as few invocations of `grep` as possible are performed (in most cases, just *1*); `{}` is the placeholder for the matching filenames.
- As pointed out in [Etan Reisner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28819545/45375), the `grep` regex should be less greedy to ensure that multiple invocations on a line are captured; furthermore, since it's now clear that only the *1st* argument should be extracted, `[^,)]*` is used to capture only up to the next argument or the closing parenthesis. (Note that this could still fail if the 1st argument itself contains a comma or parenthesis).
- The `cut` command removes the unwanted parts from `grep`'s output (strips the `__(` prefix).

---

If your `grep` implementation supports `-R` (for recursive search) and `--include` (to restrict files searched to those matching a glob), you can use

```
 grep -R --include '*.php' -sioh "__([^,)]*" . | cut -c 4-
```

---

If your `grep` implementation additionally supports `-P` (PCREs: Perl-compatible regexes), use a modified version of [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28819343/45375):

```
 grep -R --include '*.php' -siohP "__\(\K[^,)]*"
```

Using `-P` makes it easier to make the regex more robust by appending a *lookahead assertion* (`(?=...)`) to ensure that the captured token is indeed followed by literal `,` or `)`.

```
 grep -R --include '*.php' -siohP "__\(\K[^,)]*(?=[,)])"
```

Finally, note how `grep` with `-P` requires `\(` to match a literal `(`, whereas the non`-P` `grep` commands above use *basic* regular expressions, where `(` are *not* special and are treated as literals (there, you'd have to use `\(` to make them special).

In grep implementations without `-P`, invoking grep as `egrep` or using `-E` activates support for *extended* regular expressions, which have more features and are closer in syntax to PCREs, but are not as powerful.

---

A note on portability:

- `-P` (support for PCREs == Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions) is a *GNU* grep extension (won't work in BSD grep).
- `-o` is an extension found in (at least) GNU grep and BSD grep.
- `-R` and `--include` are extensions found in (at least) GNU grep and BSD grep.

Comment: I get `find: missing argument to '-exec'`. You mention platforms as a possible issue, this is Mint 17.

Comment: @ImNotMike: Sorry - my command was missing `{}` - the placeholder for the matching filenames - see my updated answer.

Comment: Plus 1 for `grep -R --include` that I missed in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use this `grep -P` (PCRE):

```
grep -HoP '__\(\K[^)]*' *.php
file.php:'foo'
file.php:'bar'
```

It finds `__\(` and `\K` resets the matched data. `[^)]*` then finds text before `)`.

Comment: An elegant solution if your grep implementation supports `-P` (GNU grep). However, unlike the OP's command, your command doesn't search the entire _subtree_ of the current dir. for `*.php` files.

Comment: Yes I assumed all `.php` files are in same directory. Otherwise as you noted `grep -R --include` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as good as anubhava's answer but it is better and works for grep without PCRE flags.

Using `[^)]*` instead of `.*` in the match will stop matches at the end of the function instead of the end of the last function call on the line.

```
$ grep -sioh "__('[^)]*')" *.php
__('foo')
__('bar')
```

Comment: Kudos for catching the issue with the regex being too greedy; however, unlike the OP's command, your command doesn't search the entire _subtree_ of the current dir. for `*.php` files.